# E: unable to locate package ros-dashing-realsense2-camera

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got error

`E: unable to locate package ros-dashing-realsense2-camera`

how do i fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399417/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-dashing-realsense2-camera/) by [ans2568](https://answers.ros.org/users/102752/ans2568/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you install this package (`sudo apt-get install ros-dashing-realsense2-camera`)?

Did you source your workspace (in your workspace `source install/setup.bash`)?

Relevant GitHub repository: https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ans2568](https://answers.ros.org/users/102752/ans2568/) on 2022-04-23**:
I solved this problem thanks!

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-23**:
Can you please accept this answer so that it can be seen in the queue of recent questions? :)